# Looking for a good technology to draw shape and manage them

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drawing

I'm currently programming an application in ASP.net MVC and I'm looking for a plug-in or anything that will help me to draw some rectangles and manage them. The rectangles should be resizable, movable and they should be compose of 8 points (at the middle of each corner and at each corner). I already found SVG, HTML 5 (canvas) and raphaeljs.com.

Do you have any good suggestion ? :)

Thx a lot guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)
- [Gephi](http://gephi.org/)

Comment: Thx a lot. Is there a way to make protovis on IE7 and IE8 ?